# Batch program will not continue

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that deletes a folder but if the folder cannot be found, then the script stops.

I am using the follow command: `rd Folder`

Anything underneath that command is not executed if the folder doesn't exist. How can I fix this?

My script:

```
net share Users /delete

taskkill /F /IM status.exe
cd C:\Users\Normal\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
del status.exe   

cd C:\Users\Normal\AppData\Roaming
rd Others /s /q

REM ANYTHING BELOW WILL NOT CONTINUE:

start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
exit

pause > nul
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that the script unexpectedly terminates early? If the script resides somewhere beneath the "Others" folder, then it certainly will die when "Others" is removed. Otherwise, your script should continue and delete itself. Of course, your script exits after deleting itself, so nothing more should happen after that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional statement to check if the folder does indeed exist before deleting. Doing so, your batch-file will not cease to run.

```
if exists c:\my_folder_to_delete\
REM Delete my folder now that I know it exists!!
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the line `rd Others /s /q` with `if exist Others (rd Others /s /q)`.

See http://ss64.com/nt/if.html for more complex conditional commands.